# Disable a CCbutton until a CCActionSequence completes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have some code similar to below:

GameScene.m

```
CCButton *yesButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:"@YES"];
[yesButton setTarget: self selector@selector(yesButtonTapped:)];
[self addChild: yesButton];

-(void)yesButtonTapped: (id)sender
{
   if(match == 1) {
      [_hud updateBallNumber: ball];
   }
}
```

HUDLayer.m

```
-(void)updateBallNumber: (Ball*)ball 
{
    int number = [ball getNumber];
    id fadeIn = [CCActionFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
    id fadeOut = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];
    id delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration: randomDelay];
    id change = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        _ballLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%i",number}];

    id sequence = [CCActionSequence actions: fadeOut,delay,change,fadeIn,nil];

    [ballLabel runAction:sequence];
}
```

It works as I would expect it to in that when the yesButton is pressed, the current number displayed in ball label fades out waits a random amount of time and then fades in a new number.

My question is how can I stop the yesButton being pressed again or ignore yesbutton presses until the sequence is complete and the new number is displayed.

I have tried using yesButton.enable, setting it at the beginning of `-(void)yesButton` to `NO` and then at the end to `YES` but this does not wait for the sequence to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do that with blocks. Change updateBallNumber as

somewhere :

```
 typedef void(^VoidBlock)();
```

in HUDLayer.m

```
-(void)updateBallNumber: (Ball*)ball withCompletion:(VoidBlock) completionBlock
{
    int number = [ball getNumber];
    VoidBlock atEnd = [completionBlock copy];  // MRC, not certain how this pans out in ARC

    id fadeIn = [CCActionFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
    id fadeOut = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];
    id delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration: randomDelay];
    id change = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
       _ballLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%i",number}];
    id complete = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        atEnd();
        [atEnd release];        // MRC
    }];
    id sequence = [CCActionSequence actions: fadeOut,delay,change,fadeIn,complete,nil];

    [ballLabel runAction:sequence];
}
```

in GameScene

```
yesButton.enabled = NO; 
[_hud updateBallNumber:ball withCompletion:^{
    yesButton.enabled = YES; 
}];
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work fine for what I need. Only slight change I had to make was  'yesButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = YES' did not work I have to use 'yesButton.enabled = YES'. is there any reason why I cant set 'isUserInteractionEnabled'in this way as the property exists?

Comment: not certain ... i dont have 'practical' 3.x experience and dont know its object model as well as prior versions. In 2.x i would prefer to 'enable/disable' the menu rather than playing with the 'touchEnabled' property. 'Enabled' merely blocks/allows touchBegan events, whilst the other adds/removes the menu as a touch responder (more complicated and tricky). I like using blocks for localized class interactions like this, avoiding the use of extensive protocols and callback structures. I'll edit the code for the benefit of others.